# Deleting objects with class inheritance with an overloaded operator delete

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to implement a mechanism for delayed deletion of objects.
Faced a problem that objects are deleted incorrectly. This mechanism does not work at all and it is similar to UB.

The following code shows the main idea and is simplified as much as possible.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::ctor\n";
    }
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::dtor\n";
    }
    virtual void invoke() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class PtrKeeper
{
public:
    PtrKeeper()
    {
        std::cout << "PtrKeeper::ctor\n";
    }
    virtual ~PtrKeeper()
    {
        std::cout << "PtrKeeper::dtor\n";
    }
    void operator delete(void* p) {
        std::cout << "PtrKeeper::operator delete\n";
        destroy(p);
    }
    static void destroy(void* p) {
        delete static_cast<T*>(p);
    }
};

struct Derived
    : public Base
    , public PtrKeeper<Derived>
{
    Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::ctor\n";
    }
    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::dtor\n";
    }
    virtual void invoke()
    {
        delete this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto obj = new Derived();
    obj->invoke();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Several compilers have different behavior:

https://onlinegdb.com/UpdlR0CE1W

```
Base::ctor
PtrKeeper::ctor
Derived::ctor
Derived::dtor
PtrKeeper::dtor
Base::dtor
PtrKeeper::operator delete
```

http://tpcg.io/_SSME38

```
Base::ctor
PtrKeeper::ctor
Derived::ctor
Derived::dtor
PtrKeeper::dtor
Base::dtor
PtrKeeper::operator delete
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

msvc 2022 (v143)

```
Base::ctor
PtrKeeper::ctor
Derived::ctor
Derived::dtor
PtrKeeper::dtor
Base::dtor
PtrKeeper::operator delete
Base::dtor
```

Also the address sanitizer on msvc has an interesting message

```
==21628==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x114eb19a50d0 in thread T3:
  object passed to delete has wrong type:
  size of the allocated type:   48 bytes;
  size of the deallocated type: 24 bytes.
```

Can anyone explain why UB is here?
How can this be fixed while retaining the original idea?

Comment: How many `Base` objects do you have (or objects derived from `Base`)? And how many times is the `Base` destructor called? If the latter is more than the former, then why would that *not* be UB?

Comment: The entire object hierarchy is shown here.
In this case, Base is an abstract class, and only Derived is inherited from it.

I can't understand why this code works in msvc, but in other compilers (gcc, clang) it fails with a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the [delete operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) (i.e. `operator delete`) and a [delete-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) (i.e. `delete foo;`)

- `operator delete` is [usually] only responsible for freeing the memory; it **must not** call the destructor - that is the job of the delete-expression.
- delete expressions will call the destructor of the object and then invoke the corresponding `operator delete` to free the memory.

delete expressions will be transformed roughly like this:

```cpp
delete something;

// is roughly equivalent to:

something->~something(); // call destructor
operator delete(something); // free memory
```

---

This is the reason why your program has UB - you're recursively trying to call the destructor and free the memory:

```cpp
void Derived::invoke() {
    // delete this;
    // will result in this code:
    ~Derived(); // call destructor
    PtrKeeper<Derived>::operator delete(this); // free memory
}

void PtrKeeper<Derived>::operator delete(void* p) {
    std::cout << "PtrKeeper::operator delete\n";
    destroy(p);
}

void PtrKeeper<Derived>::destroy(void* p) {
    // delete static_cast<T*>(p);
    // will result in this code:
    Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(p);
    d->~Derived(); // call destructor
    PtrKeeper<Derived>::operator delete(d); // free memory
}
```

Calling the destructor multiple times is UB, so anything can happen.
(you might get a compile-time error, your code might crash at runtime, or nothing happens at all are all valid responses to UB)

> [3.64 undefined behaviour](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined)
> Note 1: Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

Compilers are completely free to choose how they want to handle UB - so it is expected to see differences between different compilers when it comes to UB. (you might even get different results with the same compiler if you compile with different settings / optimizations enabled)

Here's your example compiled with gcc and `-O3`, which happens to show the recursive nature of your bug: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TKTz3ohze)

---

##### Destroying delete

If you actually want to handle the destruction of the object yourself within `operator delete` you need to use the destroying-delete version of it:

```cpp
void T::operator delete( T* ptr, std::destroying_delete_t );
```

If a destroying `operator delete` overload is present then a delete-expression like `delete x;` will not call the destructor before `operator delete`. This allows you to handle destruction manually within your operator.

Note however that this overload must be defined on the most-derived class, it can NOT be inherited from a baseclass (so in your example it would need to be defined on `Derived`).

Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/v3fvvPhPP)

```cpp
struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::ctor\n";
    }
    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::dtor\n";
    }
    virtual void invoke()
    {
        // this delete-expression will not call the destructor itself
        // because a destroying operator delete is defined for this class
        delete this;
    }

    static void operator delete(Derived* p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
        std::cout << "Derived::operator delete\n";
        
        // manually call destructor
        p->~Derived();
        
        // call global operator delete
        // to free memory
        ::operator delete(p); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! everything is perfectly clear!